# No File-Preferences Menu

Tags: 13.10, nautilus

I am using Ubuntu 13.10 and Nautilus, in order to configurate my image preview, i wanted to access the file menu.. but there are no preferences at all. is it possible to enable / disable them?

Answer (score 0):

I can't find the preferences dialog (and the hud is empty) but in between you may configure something using dconf-editor (installing the package dconf-editor) and modify some value in **org.gnome.nautilus**.

I use it to switch on treeview in list : **org.gnome.nautilus.list-view.use-tree-view**